# Flash Crucial SSD firmware through PERC 730P Mini RAID controller

Tags: raid, ssd, hardware-raid, firmware

We've got a number of Crucial drives in Dell r630 servers with PERC 730P Mini RAID controllers that need their firmware updating as they're still on version M3CR032 with the known issues.

The servers aren't live so there is always the option of taking them out of the server, plugging them into a another one with direct SATA connections and flashing them that way. But I just wondered if there's a way of flashing them through the controller. For example, using perccli. Has anyone managed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

RAID controllers almost never know anything about drive internals. Usually, even the OS doesn't know - the controller (driver) just shows the logical volume as a 'physical' drive.

Things like FW updates will most likely fail, as the update tool will not be able to 'see' the drives. I would not even try it.

Exceptions are integrated vendor solutions (like from hpe, cicsco, dell) and soft-raids.

Comment: Yeah it's a fair point, although I'm sure I have in the past managed to do this with older RAID controllers using megacli. Probably safer to just remove them from the server and use a different server with direct SATA connections.